# How to get rid of radiobutton circle when using Blazor InputRadio tag

Tags: html, css, blazor

How to get rid of radiobutton circle when using Blazor InputRadio tag. It works only in case of plain input type="radio "tag.

```
<label class="container">
   <InputRadio class="hide_circle" Value="1" />
   <span class="button_shape">Label</span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.hide_circle {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.button_shape {
    padding: 3px 6px 4px 6px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #7d7cae;
    border: 1px solid #7d7cae;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `::deep` pseudo element:

```
::deep .hide_circle {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#child-component-support), but to explain why, Blazor adds scope identifiers to your css classes, so without `::deep` your css class looks something like below. This doesn't work because the `input` child component does not contain the `b-zbwm49ki0i` attribute.

```
.hide_circle[b-zbwm49ki0i]
```

By adding the `::deep` pseudo element, it changes to the following allowing it to work on child component:

```
[b-zbwm49ki0i] .hide_circle
```